# Does the privilege status with an airline or alliance change if one redeems their miles?

Tags: loyalty-programs, american-airlines

I am a frequent traveler with American Airlines and I have accrued 84,022 miles over the last 4 years. I have 67,607 award miles right now on my AA account and I have been maintaining Gold Elite status from past 3 years. I am planning to fly international this week and I am thinking about redeeming those 67K miles towards my purchase. By doing that, will it affect my elite status or what exactly happens? Could anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, your status will not change.  Elite status is granted for earning miles, and is not affected by redeeming them.

Comment: Sweet. that's a relief. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also, you redeem award miles. Elite status is never based on award miles, but rather on status miles, elite qualifying miles or what ever other name the airline has created for them. Award and status miles are two different miles balances.